# Setting frame to view during UIPanGesture recognition

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm trying to update frames for two labels during `UIPanGesture` recognition of a `UIView` (centre grey color).

**Functionality**

I need to choose a language between English and Arabic. There is a slider button in middle (grey view) and I have applied `UIPanGesture` to that. So while swiping towards **Arabic** the language **English** should move to **centre** and assumes that its selected and vice versa.

I tried my level best but I can only make upto this. Frames are not setting properly and I don't know is there any other easy way to do this.

**Code**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
    [dragview addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
}


- (void)handleGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint velocity = [gestureRecognizer velocityInView: gestureRecognizer.view];
    CGPoint location = [gestureRecognizer locationInView: gestureRecognizer.view];

    if(velocity.x > 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"gesture went right");
        if (dragview.frame.origin.x + dragview.frame.size.width >= dragV.frame.size.width) {
            [dragview setFrame:CGRectMake(dragV.frame.size.width - dragview.frame.size.width, dragview.frame.origin.y, dragview.frame.size.width, dragview.frame.size.height)];
            english.center = CGPointMake(dragV.frame.size.width  / 2,
                                                              dragV.frame.size.height / 2);
        } else {
            float dX = location.x-panCoord.x;
            gestureRecognizer.view.frame = CGRectMake(gestureRecognizer.view.frame.origin.x+dX, 0, gestureRecognizer.view.frame.size.width, gestureRecognizer.view.frame.size.height);
            [english setFrame:CGRectMake(english.frame.origin.x + 1.0f, english.frame.origin.y, english.frame.size.width, english.frame.size.height)];
            [arabic setFrame:CGRectMake(arabic.frame.origin.x + 1.0f, arabic.frame.origin.y, arabic.frame.size.width, arabic.frame.size.height)];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"gesture went left");
        if (dragview.frame.origin.x <= 0) {
            [dragview setFrame:CGRectMake(0, dragview.frame.origin.y, dragview.frame.size.width, dragview.frame.size.height)];
            arabic.center = CGPointMake(dragV.frame.size.width  / 2,
                                         dragV.frame.size.height / 2);
        } else {
            float dX = location.x+panCoord.x;
            gestureRecognizer.view.frame = CGRectMake(gestureRecognizer.view.frame.origin.x+dX, 0, gestureRecognizer.view.frame.size.width, gestureRecognizer.view.frame.size.height);
            [english setFrame:CGRectMake(english.frame.origin.x - 1.0f, english.frame.origin.y, english.frame.size.width, english.frame.size.height)];
            [arabic setFrame:CGRectMake(arabic.frame.origin.x - 1.0f, arabic.frame.origin.y, arabic.frame.size.width, arabic.frame.size.height)];
        }
    }
}
```

**Screenshots**

Initially it looks like this,

[image]

While dragging towards arabic,

[image]

While dragging towards english,
[image]

Answers are appreciated!!

Comment: Do you use auto layout?

Comment: No I use autoresizing

Comment: Can you send me your code?I will help you

Comment: @user3182143 Please find the code here https://www.dropbox.com/s/4wr20ml7zp7wu0s/tester.zip?dl=0

Comment: I am getting empty page If I run your application.

Comment: Im sorry in storyboard dragV is hidden. Please make it enable.

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: I run with iPhone 5s also.it works perfectly.Especially I pan the view using middle finger.It works fine and perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I got output.I tried your code and I used SwipeGestureRecognizer code.It works fine now.

I tried with 2 optins

**OPTION 1:SwipeGestureRecognizer**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   // Swipe Left
   UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeLeft:)];
   swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
   [arabicView addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];

   // Swipe Right
   UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeRight:)];
   swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
   [englishView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
}

- (void)handleSwipeLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{
  [self performSelector:@selector(moveAtRight) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01f];
}

- (void)handleSwipeRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{
  [self performSelector:@selector(moveAtLeft) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01f];
}


-(void)moveAtRight
{
  englishView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 53, 53);
  englishView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
  arabicView.frame = CGRectMake(53, 0, 205, 53);
  english.text = @"English";
  arabic.text = @"Arabic";
  arabicView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
  [dragview removeFromSuperview];
}


-(void)moveAtLeft
{
  englishView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 205, 53);
  arabicView.frame = CGRectMake(205, 0, 53, 53);
  arabicView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
  englishView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
  english.text = @"English";
  arabic.text = @"Arabic";
  [dragview removeFromSuperview];
}
```

In above code I set background color to blue.If you want to any other color change.

**At Initial**

[image]

**When I swipe towards Arabic**

[image]

**When I swipe towards English**

[image]

Above these are output.

**OPTION 2:PanGestureRecognizer**

Now I tried with your PanGestureRecognizer Code.I set frame and background color for englishView and arabicView separately.Now it works fine.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

  _drawPath = [UIBezierPath
                          bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, 35)
                          byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight | UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight)
                          cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(4, 4)
                          ];
  _rectLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
  _rectLayer.path = _drawPath.CGPath;
  _rectLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
  _rectLayer.lineWidth = 2.0f;
  _rectLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
  _rectLayer.strokeEnd = 0.f;
  [vi.layer addSublayer:_rectLayer];

  [self drawRectangle:nil];

  UIPanGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
  [gesture setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
  [gesture setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
  [englishView addGestureRecognizer:gesture];

  UIPanGestureRecognizer *gesture1 = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
  [gesture1 setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
  [gesture1 setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
  [arabicView addGestureRecognizer:gesture1];
}

- (void)handleGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{

   if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
   {
      NSLog(@"Changed");
      CGPoint velocity = [gestureRecognizer velocityInView:gestureRecognizer.view];
      CGPoint translation = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:gestureRecognizer.view];

      if(velocity.x > 0)
      {
            NSLog(@"gesture went right");
            gestureRecognizer.view.frame = CGRectMake(gestureRecognizer.view.frame.origin.x + translation.x, 0, gestureRecognizer.view.frame.size.width, gestureRecognizer.view.frame.size.height);
            NSLog(@"The gestureRecognizer frame is - %@",NSStringFromCGRect(gestureRecognizer.view.frame));
            [englishView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, englishView.frame.origin.y, 205, englishView.frame.size.height)];
            [englishView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(15/255.0f) green:(97/255.0f) blue:(163/255.0f) alpha:1.0f]];
            [arabicView setFrame:CGRectMake(205, arabicView.frame.origin.y, 53, arabicView.frame.size.height)];
            [arabicView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
            [gestureRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:dragV];
            [dragview removeFromSuperview];

    }
    else
    {
            NSLog(@"gesture went left");
            gestureRecognizer.view.frame = CGRectMake(gestureRecognizer.view.frame.origin.x + translation.x, 0, gestureRecognizer.view.frame.size.width, gestureRecognizer.view.frame.size.height);
            [arabicView setFrame:CGRectMake(53, arabicView.frame.origin.y, 205, arabicView.frame.size.height)];
            [englishView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, englishView.frame.origin.y,53,englishView.frame.size.height)];
            [arabicView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(15/255.0f) green:(97/255.0f) blue:(163/255.0f) alpha:1.0f]];
            [englishView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
            [gestureRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:dragV];
            [dragview removeFromSuperview];
    }
  }
}
```

**At First once I run the app**

[image]

**Middle Finger towards Arabic View**

[image]

**Middle Finger towards English View**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and using swipe gesture is very easy but i need to pan the middle handler towards both extreme to choose a language. Please check with my updated code https://www.dropbox.com/s/qop3ae5nrklylbp/tester.zip?dl=0

Comment: Maniganda Saravanan check with my answer